# Buying a house 50/50

Tags: mortgage, rental-property, rent, home-equity

I'm thinking on buying a house with my Business Partner. I would be living on it. We are thinking on going 50/50 on the loan and down payment and hoa and repairs . Since I would be living there we were thinking on me paying the utilities and since I live there I would pay my 50% of the monthly payment plus extra 25%. So pretty much I would be covering 75% of the monthly payment and getting only 50% of the equity is this a good deal ?

Comment: Why do you want to roll the utilities in like that? Why not you each pay 50% of the mortgage/insurance/taxes and you pay all the utilities?

Comment: Bad idea all around.

Answer (score 7):

This question is really a variation of rent vs buy. 
Try looking at it this way - If you bought it 50/50 and rented it out, what would you both get? Now, moved in, you are effectively collecting that rent, but half is your own money, half is from the partner. 
Is the half you are getting the from the partner equal to 1/4 of the mortgage.

This sounds convoluted, but once you spell all the numbers out, it would be clear.

Without the deal as you present it, you'd be paying the partner to 'live in his half.'

Answer (score 0):

I don't like it using percentages makes no sense.  Find out what market value is for rent and pay 1/2 of that to your partner, adjust annually.   You partner should be protected from inflation if he is going to invest in real estate.